# How to get linear acceleration data from SensorManager?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, sensors

I am trying to display the linear acceleration of the phone inside a textview, on an Android app, using Kotlin.

In one activity, I have

```kotlin
var sensorManager : SensorManager? = null
var lastUpdatedDate : Date? = null
```

Then, inside the `onCreate()` method I have

```kotlin
lastUpdatedDate = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
sensorManager = getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
```

And my `onSensorChanged()` method is as follows:

```kotlin
@Override
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
    when (event?.sensor?.type) {
        Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION -> {
            timer_since_started_detecting.text = event.values[0].toString()
        }
    }
}
```

From my understanding, `onSensorChanged()` gets called (when the activity class extends `SensorEventListener`) every time one of the sensors the phone has updates its value.

From other answers and from the documentation, I should be able to see the type of sensor that changed its value, and in my case, if it is the linear acceleration sensor, the new value should be written inside my textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, onSensorChanged() gets called (when the activity class extends SensorEventListener) every time one of the sensors the phone has updates its value.

You also need to call `registerListener()` on `SensorManager`, supplying your listener and the sensor that you want. See:

- [The `SensorManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager)
- [The sensors overview documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview#sensors-monitor)

Comment: That's what was missing! Thank you for the links, for some reason looking through android's documentation on [motion sensors](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion) I thought that was all the documentation on it. It perfectly works now.